# How to download and use the universal sentence encoder instead of loading it from url

Tags: python, tensorflow, sentence-similarity

I am using the universal sentence encoder to find sentence similarity. below is the code that i use to load the model

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
model = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual-large/3")
```

Here, instead of lookin at the url in tensorflow hub, Is there a way to download the model programmatically to a local location and load the model from local filesystem

Comment: Hey were you able to download the model? I'm trying to do the same

Answer (score 2):

Well i am not sure and i haven't tried it but i checked the source of the `hub.load()` and i found some interesting facts may be they help you for your problem

First of all the doc says

> This function is roughly equivalent to the TF2 function
> `tf.saved_model.load()` on the result of `hub.resolve(handle)`.
> Calling this   function requires TF 1.14 or newer. It can be called
> both in eager and graph   mode.

that means the function can handle both URL or saved model in a file system, to confirm that i checked the documentation of `hub.resolve()` which is being used internally in `hub.load()` and there i found some thing of your interest

```
def resolve(handle):
  """Resolves a module handle into a path.
  This function works both for plain TF2 SavedModels and the legacy TF1 Hub
  format.
  Resolves a module handle into a path by downloading and caching in
  location specified by TF_HUB_CACHE_DIR if needed.
  Currently, three types of module handles are supported:
    1) Smart URL resolvers such as tfhub.dev, e.g.:
       https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim128/1.
    2) A directory on a file system supported by Tensorflow containing module
       files. This may include a local directory (e.g. /usr/local/mymodule) or a
       Google Cloud Storage bucket (gs://mymodule).
    3) A URL pointing to a TGZ archive of a module, e.g.
       https://example.com/mymodule.tar.gz.
  Args:
    handle: (string) the Module handle to resolve.
  Returns:
    A string representing the Module path.
  """
  return registry.resolver(handle)
```

The documentation clearly says it supports the path to the local file system which points to the module/model files, you should now perform some experiments and give it a try. For more details have a look on [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/v0.12.0/tensorflow_hub/module_v2.py#L50-L108) source file